# Evitar registro duplicados en tabla pivote en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy agregando registros en mi tabla pivote, a un usuario se le asigna un contrato diferente, pero no se como hacer para que no me inserte un registro duplicado. El usuario puede tener muchos contratos. Este es el código:

```
$usuario = $_POST['user'];
$contrato = $_POST['contract']; 

$user = User::find($usuario);
$user->contracts()->attach($contrato);
```

Comment: Que es lo que recibes en `$_POST['user']` y `$_POST['contract']`, son las ids? Sería útil saber como definiste la relación `contracts()` en el modelo `User`, puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/314385/edit) la pregunta y agregarlo? También si un usuario puede tener muchos contratos, o solo deseas reeplazar el que tiene relacionado por el nuevo que llega en el request.

Comment: Puedes hacer una validación. Antes de hacer el insert haces un select haber si ya existe ese registro en tu tabla, de ser así retornas un error.

Comment: y como haria esa validacion

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que usar otro `metodo` que es el `sync`

```
$user->contracts()->sync($contrato);
```

lo cual primero aplica `dettach` para eliminar las enterioes relaciones de los parametros que se le pasan

```
$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: si utilizo sync me elimina los contratos asignados anteriormente, y un numero N de contratos que se pueden asignar

Comment: exacto, eso es para evitar duplicidad, por eso al enviar una relacion ya existente, en la tabla pivote, elimina el anterior y crea una nueva, si no existe la crea, el resto que ha sido relacionada ya sea de `contrato` o `usuario` no se ve afectada